# Python/Pandas Using different colors for data points in a step function

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, charts

I've been trying to plot parts of a pandas dataframe using the Matplotlib Step-function. However I'm unable to colorize individual datapoints or "steps" based on other categories that are part that instance.

Precisely I want to create a merit-order graph that plots operating costs over capacity as a single step chart.

New Code

```
df = pd.read_csv("merit_v1.csv")
df = df[df.energy_source != "Hydro"]

df = df.sort_values(by="margC",ascending=True)

df["capacity"] = round(df["capacity"].cumsum() / 1000, 3)
y = df["margC"].tolist()
x = df["capacity"].tolist()

x_app = x[1:] 
y_app = y[:len(y)-1]

x = x + x_app + [0]
y = y + y_app + [y[0]]

x = sorted(x)
y = sorted(y)

colors = []
energy = df["energy_source"].tolist()
for item in energy:
    if item == "Nuclear":
            color = "#DDF45B"
    if item == "Coal":
            color = "#141115"
    if item == "Lignite":
            color = "#8D6346"
    if item == "Bioenergy":
            color = "#5A720F"
    if item == "Natural Gas":
            color = "#4C2B36"
    if item == "Oil":
            color = "#C1A5A9"
    colors.append(color)

colors = list(np.repeat(colors, 2))

points = np.array([x, y]).T.reshape(-1, 1, 2)
segments = np.concatenate([points[:-1], points[1:]], axis=1)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

lc = LineCollection(segments, color = colors)

lc.set_linewidth(2)
line = ax.add_collection(lc)

ax.set_xlim(-5, max(x) + 5)
ax.set_ylim(0, max(y) + 5)

ax.fill_between(x,y, facecolor="w")
ax.set_title("Merit-Order des europäischen Kraftwerkparks")
ax.set_xlabel('Kummulierte Leistung GW')
ax.set_ylabel('Grenzkosten €/MWh')
plt.show()
```

Comment: Correct. `plt.step`, like `plt.plot` are of a single color. You do have the option to use a `LineCollection` instead.

Comment: I think it's gonna take me quite a while to figure this out since I'm fairly new to python but thats ok. However I only find examples for the regular line plot, no idea how to transfer this concept to step charts. Thanks anyway!

Comment: [Here](https://matplotlib.org/gallery/lines_bars_and_markers/multicolored_line.html) is an example. To produce steps you would need to duplicate each point along x, such that it has a y value for the lower and upper part of the step.

Comment: After a while I figured it out, you've helped me so much! All the steps have the correct colors now and are in step-chart form. The last thing missing that I'm not able to solve right now is, to use 'fill_inbetween' to colorize the area underneath the chart with the same color according to the segments. I've been trying to use the 'where" argument but I'm not really getting far.

Comment: That sounds complicated. You would need as many `fill_between`s as you have different colors, but it should work. I guess I cannot help without seeing the problem in terms of code. But I was thinking, if you want to fill the area below a step curve with the same colors as the step itself the resulting plot should be the same as a simple `bar` plot without gaps in between the bars - this might be much easier to achieve.

Comment: I edited my post to show my current code. A bar plot is what I wanted to use at first, but the width of the bars need to reflect the capacity of the powerplant and be be part of the xaxis, not only be visual.

Comment: Note that I'd be happy to produce an answer if there was a [mcve] available, i.e. a code one can copy, paste and run and where some data is included *inside* the code.  (Don't use your real data, just some mock up data that would show a similar plot)

Comment: I just solved it. Its possible to do it with the bar chart by extending the width far enough so it stays hidden behind the next bar and aligning it with its left edge. Thank you so much for your help, even though it was simpler than I thought in the end!

Comment: I would make the bar widths exactly as wide as the distance between two points, else this would only work if the steps point upwards.